# Alignment in dimension of matrices

Tags: pandas, numpy, neural-network

I tried to run this code with my data but I obtained this error:

> "ValueError: shapes (3,126) and (3,126) not aligned: 126 (dim 1) != 3
>   (dim 0)"

I'm doing the neural network and I don't want to use libraries which are suitable for Neural Network like TensorFlow.

```
X = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\users\Hasan\Desktop\ANN\x.xlsx")
y = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\users\Hasan\Desktop\ANN\y.xlsx")
xPredicted = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\users\Hasan\Desktop\ANN\xpredict.xlsx")

self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize)
self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize)
self.z = np.dot(X, self.W1) 
self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z) # activation function
self.z3 = np.dot(self.z2, self.W2) 
o = self.sigmoid(self.z3) # final activation function
```

> ValueError: shapes (3,126) and (3,126) not aligned: 126 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Comment: Which line gives the error? What are the shapes of `x`, `y` and `xPredicted`?

Comment: @nnnmmm in the line which is producing dot product `self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize)` and this also `self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize)`

Comment: review docs for np.dot

Comment: @HosseinAmini you might need to transpose one of your matrices in order to carry out the dot product

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud Which one? input or output?