# Mismatching matrix sizes on dot product of same matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do the dot product between the same matrix, somehow the following error occurs: 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (101,2) (101,) .

Clearly it does not make much sense, at least to me, since I am doing the dot product between the same two matrices.

```
def RidgeRegression(X, t, theta, alpha, T, ridgeCoef):
    vtheta = np.zeros([T,2,1])
    N = len(t) # number of training examples
    error = np.zeros(T)
    batch = 0
    for it in range(T):
        for numBatch in range(4):
            y = np.dot(X[batch:batch+101], theta) - t[batch:batch+101]     
            grad = 1/2*np.dot(X[batch:batch+101].T,y)+
            np.dot(X[batch:batch+101].T, X[batch:batch+101])
            theta = theta - (alpha/101) * grad
            batch +=101
        error[it] = sum(np.dot(X, theta) - t)/N
        vtheta[it,:] = theta.reshape(2,1)
        batch = 0

    return vtheta, error
```

```
grad = 1/2*np.dot(X[batch:batch+101].T,y) +
      np.dot(X[batch:batch+101].T, X[batch:batch+101])
```

This where the dot product error occurs.

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (101,2) (101,)

Error

Comment: You want the element bitwise product?

Comment: The error message isn't from the `dot`.

Comment: Recent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197904/alignment-in-dimension-of-matrices is an example of `dot` dimension error.

Comment: The problem occurs if I select a batch, some how the dot product between X and theta does not output a 101 vector, instead it outputs a 101,2 matrix. There is where dimension error happens

Comment: OK never mind I have rewritten what I had and somehow the error is gone....Even though the code is completely analogous to the one above

Comment: It may have been the `+` operator.